# How does charge move in conducter which is between two connected conductors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, conductors

[image]

Two square conductors with neutral charge and surface $A$ and $d<<\sqrt{A}$.

The conductor in the middle is the same shape but with a very small hight, $dh$, and is charged with $q$

How to determine the charge distribution on each of the edges of the conductor?

I know the E field on the edges of the middle conductor $E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$. Also the potential in the neutral boards is the same because they are wired. Any direction on how to proceed from here?

Edit - added position vectors and made this attempt:

The middle plate is a conductor and must have equal potential on its surface, so define $V(r_2)$ for the upper and lower edges. For the neutral plates it is $V(r_1)$ because they are wired. Also $r_2-r_1=d$ and $r_3-r_2=2d$.

Then $V(r_1)-V(r_2)= -\int_{r_2}^{r_1} \frac{\sigma_1}{\epsilon_0}\ dr = V(r_2)-V(r_3)=-\int_{r_3}^{r_2} \frac{\sigma_2}{\epsilon_0}\ dr$. We get

$\frac{\sigma_1}{\epsilon_0}(r_1-r_2)=\frac{\sigma_2}{\epsilon_0}(r_2-r_3)$. Plugging $d$ gives $\sigma_1=2\sigma_2$

Comment: Do you need an exact answer, or is it acceptable to use the "large plate" approximation (neglecting fringing)?

Comment: I think large plate approximation is good if  $d<<\sqrt{A}$

Comment: And you're controlling the potential difference between the two electrodes? i.e. you say you want to determine the charge distribution, but you don't say what "knowns" you are starting from.

Comment: @ThePhoton It is specified that the outer plates are neutral as a whole and the inner plate has charge $q$. There is enough information here.

Comment: I don't control them. I insert the middle one which is charged, the others are not. all the knowns are what I wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat this as two parallel capacitors. One between the top plate and the top of the middle plate, and one between the bottom plate and the bottom of the middle plate.

Since the dielectric thickness of the lower capacitor is twice that of the upper capacitor, it will have half the capacitance.

So the charge "stored" in the lower capacitor will be $q/3$ and the charge "stored" in the upper capacitor will $2q/3$.

Put another way, there will be $-2q/3$ on the upper plate, $2q/3$ on the upper surface of the middle plate, $q/3$ on the lower surface of the middle plate, and $-q/3$ on the lower plate.

Edit to add:

In comments you asked,

> Is there a way to solve it with fields/potential?

You know the potentials of the top and bottom plate are equal. And the potentials of the top and bottom surfaces of the middle plate.

And the field between two "broad" planes of charge is uniform (You can show this with Gauss's Law).

Then since the potential is the integral of the field  along a path, and the path from the top plate to the middle plate is half the distance as the path from the bottom plate to the middle plate, the field strength must be twice as high in the upper dielectric as in the lower dielectric.

Then since
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_r}$$
(the differential form of Gauss's Law), the charge on the top surface of the middle plate must be double the charge on the bottom surface. (Put in more hand-wavy terms, there must be more charge on the top surface to terminate the more closely spaced field lines)

Comment: Thanks, we didn't learn capacitors at the time I got that question. Is there a way to solve it with fields/potential?

Comment: Can you check my edit please? I tried to implement what you wrote without the differential Gauss's Law, is it correct?